# External encryption and signing properties files for cxf

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I need to call a secured web service using CXF. I have two files `server.properties` and `client.properties` which basically define the username, alias, password, and the location of the certificate store for signing and encrypting outgoing ws requests.

This works very well when the properties files are on the classpath in a jar.

Now I would like to have the properties files outside of a jar in a configuration folder.
Is it possible? I have tried to add the file location to the classpath, then the configuration folder to the classpath but it didn't work.

I always get this exception:

```
org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: General security error (Cannot load the resource client.properties)
```

Comment: Are you setting up CXF from within Spring or on its own?

Comment: From within Spring, i've configured an out interceptor.
This is the configuration:
`<bean id="wss4jOut" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">`
     `<constructor-arg>`
        `<map>`
           `<entry key="user" value="${ws.security.username}" />`
           `<entry key="encryptionUser" value="server" />`
            `...`
            `<entry key="encryptionPropFile" value="${ws.security.encryption.client.file}"/>`
                `...`
           `</map>`
        `</constructor-arg>`
`</bean>`

Comment: any updates ? I'm experiencing the same issue